# few locations not showing up on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have list of stores and when i click on any one depending on their latitude and longitude values which i get from a web server i show them on the map. some of them show up but some wont...i know this is not a good question....but i am just expecting if someone who might have experienced the same problem might help.

here is the code:

```
Double Storelat = (FeedListViewActivity.lat);
        Double Storelng = (FeedListViewActivity.lng);

        storeLocation = new GeoPoint((int) (Storelat * 1E6), (int) (Storelng * 1E6));


public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        Point locationPoint1 = new Point();

        Projection projection1 = mapView.getProjection();
        projection1.toPixels(storeLocation, locationPoint1);

        Paint containerPaint = new Paint();
        containerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        int containerX1 = locationPoint1.x;
        int containerY1 = locationPoint1.y;

        if (shadow) {
            containerX1 += CONTAINER_SHADOW_OFFSET;
            containerY1 += CONTAINER_SHADOW_OFFSET;
            containerPaint.setARGB(90, 0, 0, 0);
            canvas.drawCircle(containerX1, containerY1, CONTAINER_RADIUS,
                    containerPaint);

        } else {
            containerPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(containerX1, containerY1, CONTAINER_RADIUS,
                    containerPaint);
        }
}
```

and these are the values i get from the webserver:

working:

lat = 18.5170002
lng = 73.858078

not working:

lat = 18.618679
lng = 73.8037491

Comment: is it by any chance because of the difference of no.of digits after decimal point??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your answer is in your question itself

```
working:

lat = 18.5170002 lng = 73.858078

not working:

lat = 18.618679 lng = 73.8037491
```

as per above provided thing you can see the precision difference i have also faced the same problem be 6 months, and i have made that 6 precision to 8 precision and was working well then.

if you pass 18.618679 then it will treat it as 0.18618679 for confirmation try to zoom out up-to level 2 or 3 you will get your point at unexpected place.